# sample() function excluding reoccuring values R

Tags: r, random, sample

I want to choose random values of a vector and print them without having the possibility of reoccuring the same numbers. E.g 
If 32 has already been printed out, it should not be possible to print this number (or save this number in another variable) again. How can I do this?

```
test <- c(1,32,4,92,20)
for (i in 1:4){
  print(sample(test,size = 1))}
```

Comment: have you used `replace = FALSE`  `sample(test, 4, replace = FALSE)`

Comment: Also, you probably just want `sample(test,size = 4,replace = FALSE)` rather than the `for` loop. (Please note how I added your code to the question; please make sure to do that in the future rather than screenshots.)

Comment: you dont need to use a loop here. You could just change the size to 4. The default for sample is FALSE for replace, so it would not be able to select the same number twice

Comment: Yeah, I tried replace = FALSE. The thing is I have to write a model and I have to pick one value at a time to test if the model is varying because of it. Thus I have to use size=1 and have the value that it already picked and printed out not being used again for a pick.  With replace=FALSE I ended up getting a similar result with a value duplicating